# Python Spacy NLP - TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected unicode, got str)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I was getting the following error while i was trying to read a txt file in spacy.

> TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected unicode, got str)

Here is the code below

```
from __future__  import unicode_literals
import spacy
nlp= spacy.load('en')
doc_file = nlp(open("example.txt").read())
```

Comment: `doc_file = nlp(open("example.txt").read().decode())` ?

Comment: I'm getting the following error when i add decode to it

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 955: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I think all you need is declare `doc = ''`, then read the  file correctly as UTF8: `with codecs.open(fpath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fr: doc = fr.read()` and then `doc_file =  nlp(doc)`

Answer (score 1):

you should use nlp= spacy.blank('en') instead of spacy.load('en').

```
nlp= spacy.blank('en')
doc_file = nlp(open("example.txt").read())
```